# Observer pattern .. spring events vs java ee6 events observer pattern

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I need to implement an observer pattern in java,

And i am quite famailiar with spring events.. however i recently was introduced to java ee 6 observer pattern.

I notice that spring makes it seem easier, but it has no asynchronous ability our of the box, i have to configure an executor... and then all my events are asycnhronous...

Is there anyway in Spring to have some events that are asyc and some are sync...

Is java ee 6 observer pattern implementation better than springs?... Does it allow this, any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**in spring you have to create the asynchronous runner.**